# Jekyll strip_html but allow certain HTML tags

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In my Jekyll post I'm using `strip_html` to display a brief 50-word intro of the post on the main page:

```
<p>{{ post.content | strip_html | truncatewords:50 }}</p>
```

`strip_html` removes all HTML from this excerpt. But I'd like so include some HTML, specifically `<i>` and `<p>`.

Is there a configuration (`_config.yaml`) for doing that, or is there a limitation where `strip_html` doesn't have customization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK there is no built-in way to customize `strip_html`.

If you have an exclusive -- and not so long -- list of your wanted tags, you may first use `replace` on the tags you want to keep to replace them with non html markers, then use `strip_html`, and `replace` again to get back the html:

```
{% assign preprocessed_content=post.content | replace: '<p>', '__p__' %}
{% assign preprocessed_content=preprocessed_content | replace: '</p>', '__/p__' %}

{% assign truncated_content=preprocessed_content | strip_html | truncatewords:50 %}

{% assign cleaned_content=truncated_content | replace: '__p__', '<p>' %}
{% assign cleaned_content=cleaned_content | replace: '__/p__', '</p>' %}

<p>{{ cleaned_content }}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out.